# How to move from Secondactivity to Mainactivity after animation is complete?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-intent

Sorry I am a bit new to stack overflow but hopefully the question is understandable!

I talked to a staff memeber/community member who showed me Intent to go from 1 activity(in my case GlobeActivity where my animation is stored) to another activity( MainActivity where username/password is stored). But the animation does not show up, instead it cuts directly to MainActivity.

Anyone got some suggestions to why and how to make it so that **when** animation is finished, it re-directs/ transitions to MainActivity **without** use of buttons?

Here is my code so far:

GlobeActivity( my SecondActivity):

```
package com.example.testerino2022

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class GlobeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_globe)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textGlobeScreen)
        textView.animate().translationX(1050F).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2500)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

}
```

MainActivity(has default code in it );

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textView.animate()
   .translationX(1050F)
   .setDuration(1000)
   .setStartDelay(2500)
   .withEndAction {
       startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
       finish()
  }
```

Comment: How does this even listen to the animation event. This is just like any countdown

Comment: yes it's like a countdown but it works after all

Comment: Does that sound productive

Comment: Things should work right and effectively not just work

Comment: What if the animation duration is later changed to 5 seconds and the handler is 3 seconds, that will just change activities befor ethe animation object is closed and can cause memory leaks. Will one have to update the duration everywhere?

Comment: you are so right i will update my code accordingly

Comment: That would be great

Comment: yes i missed this please i'm sorry please can you help me.

Comment: There are some answers below that have implemented the ViewPropertyAnimator method. Please check them out

Comment: I updated my code. I will be glad if you support

Answer (score 2):

You can use animation listener

```
 textView.animate().translationX(1050F).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2500).setListener(
        object: Animator.AnimatorListener{
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }
    )
```

Comment: I am not yet familiar with animation listener but will more learn about it and give it a try! Thanks for tip

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the `ViewPropertyAnimator` stuff you're already using - just add `withEndAction`:

```
textView.animate()
    .translationX(1050F)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .setStartDelay(2500)
    .withEndAction {
        startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip! Will be sure to give it a try tomorrow and see how it works :)

Comment: @JosefM it's good to know in general! You can even do stuff like kick off another animation when the first one finishes

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the launcher activity from MainActivity to GlobeActivity in the app's manifest?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I dont think I did but did manage to solve it though thanks to the awesome people here posting different working solutions, but will definately keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the view or element that is being animated, assuming an ImageView. You can do this with the ViewPropertyAnimator.

```
ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

imageView.animate()
    .translationX(1050F)
    .setDuration(2000)
    .setStartDelay(1000)
    .withEndAction {
        startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
```

## Explanation

1. `translationX(float value)` - This method will cause the View's translationX property to be animated to the specified value
2. `setDuration(long duration)` - Sets the duration for the underlying animator that animates the requested properties.
3. `setStartDelay(long startDelay)` - Sets the startDelay for the underlying animator that animates the requested properties.
4. `withEndAction(Runnable runnable)` - Specifies an action to take place when the next animation ends.

For more information on this, check this out : -> [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator)